# What is the method to record and calculate time?

Tags: c#, datetime, methods, time

I want to create a method that takes two variables timeIn and timeOut and compare the times between the two to draw a difference.

How can I make it so that that timeIn is recorded at time now, and timeOut would also be a time for the present date? 
It is as if I checked into a parking lot, and then check out sort thing.

Could I take timeOut and subtract it from timeIn to get the difference?

I am using c# code.

Comment: Did you mean "a date for the present time" or "a time for the present date"?..

Comment: I meant a time for the present date, sorry i got confused durp.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this :

```
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

       doLogWork() ...

    sw.Stop();

Console.Write(       sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " Sec    / " +
                    ((float)sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds / (float)60).ToString("N2") + 
                    " min" );
```

### edit

DONT USE TIMESPAN

ticks represented in `Stopwatch` are based on a combination of the **hardware of the machine** and the operating system. 
 Contrast this to `TimeSpan` where `Ticks` are defined as `100 nanosecond intervals` -- which is obviously machine/OS **independent**.

Comment: sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " Sec    / " + ((float)sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds / (float)60).ToString("N2") + " min"  ---- what does this line do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

DateTime - DateTime will give a TimeSpan object telling how much time passed between the two.